# loading several forms in a div but every form disappears when i click submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an index page, i am loading several pages in a div in that page by clicking links , some of them are forms(pages). When i click submit, the information is processed correctly and it is stored in the database but the page disappears because of which i am unable to see some useful information like errors generated after form validation. I want that the page should not disappear after loading. A page can be shown in the same div only when i click on the link for that page.

I am using php, javascript, jquery, MySqL.

Any help ??

Answer (score 2):

That is the default behavior of forms submit. If I am not mistaken you need to prevent the default behavior on that form submit callback. If the considering form have an id of `formID` then You can do this

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e){
   //prevent default Behaviour
   e.preventDefault();

});
```

And in that case you have to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to submit form data into server without reloading the page.

Comment: **i am using this script**  `$( document ).ready( function() {
$( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();   
e.stopPropagation();
$( '#content' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
});
});`